# Return view-versus-a-copy, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.readexcel(excel_name)
groupColumn = df('Group') #There is a column named Group in excel_name
for row in range(1, len(df)):
   if "unused" in groupColumn[row]:
   groupColumn[row] = "input logic unused"
```

When I try to run the above code I get the following error
**A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame**

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
groupColumn[row] = "input logic unused" + str(unusedPinsCount)

How to avoid this?

Comment: You chould get `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable` with `groupColumn = df('Group')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Group":["unused","used","used","unused"],
                   "Value":[1,2,3,4]})
#     Group  Value
# 0  unused      1
# 1    used      2
# 2    used      3
# 3  unused      4

df.loc[df["Group"]=="unused", "Group"]="input logic unused"

#                 Group  Value
# 0  input logic unused      1
# 1                used      2
# 2                used      3
# 3  input logic unused      4
```